# How to mock SignInManager<TUser, TKey>.HasBeenVerifiedAsync() method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-identity, moq, asp.net-identity-2

Is there a way to mock `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager<TUser, TKey>.HasBeenVerifiedAsync()` method?

I am getting this exception when mocking the method

```
System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.HasBeenVerifiedAsync()
```

Which is OK, I did not know that this method isn't virtual. Is it possible to mock it by its internals, or is there any other workaround?

Comment: I would write an interface containing all the methods on this class that you use.  You can then use the interface as a dependency and easily mock out the interface in your tests.  The implementation will be easy as you will be simply forwarding on calls to the `SignInManager`.

Comment: I agree with Oliver.  The wrapper implementation class should be pretty straightforward.  If you really don't want to use this you're stuck paying for software that can intercept non-virtual methods, like TypeMock.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to mock `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager<TUser, TKey>.HasBeenVerifiedAsync()` with Typemock isolator because it's allows you to mock almost everything also ASP.NET MVC.

Here is an example for a method that uses the `HasBeenVerifiedAsync()` method (from visual studio MVC template):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(string provider, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
{
    // Require that the user has already logged in via username/password or external login
    if (!await SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync())
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = provider, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
}
```

And this is the test :

```
[TestMethod,Isolated]
public async void TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    AccountController controller = new AccountController();
    // Mocking SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync()
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => controller.SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync()).WillReturn(Task.FromResult(true));

    // Act
    var result = await controller.VerifyCode("tester", "test.com", true) as ViewResult ;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("tester", (result.Model as VerifyCodeViewModel).Provider);
    Assert.AreEqual("test.com", (result.Model as VerifyCodeViewModel).ReturnUrl);
    Assert.IsTrue((result.Model as VerifyCodeViewModel).RememberMe);
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fmockingaspdotnetmvc.htm).